# How to figure out which oldest version (git tag or GitHub release) includes given commit/PR?

Tags: git, github

Say I've found a pull request on GitHub that fixes my problem. The PR is already merged, but I still have the problem.

So I want to figure out whether the fix is included into the version I'm using.

I have a commit id and a PR id, and I would like to determine the oldest git tag which includes them.

It's possible via `git tag --contains <commit>`, but that requires cloning the repo.

**How do I figure that out via GitHub UI**?

PS Comparing commit date against tag date is not enough, because branches. A commit may be older than tag but still not be included into that tag.

Comment: `git tag --contains <commit>` will get you the list of tags.  Defining "oldest" is tricky (and probably not useful in general, as it depends too much on the tag names) but if there are not too many tags, this tends to suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't search via commit ID or message on GitHub.com, though you can locally.

What you CAN do is search by specific code within the repository - so if you know what changed in those commits, you can search for that text within your own version. (Assuming your version is a forked version.)